# MYSQL How to find numbers near a string

Tags: mysql

I have one of these variations in a field:

```
Amount Used: 4/11
Amount Used : 4 / 11
4 / 11  Amount Used
```

Each row in my table contains one of these variations with a different set of numbers.

**Is it be possible to find the *numbers* near the string** `Amount Used`, **regardless of whatever tiny variations there may be in the syntax near it?**

I've atleast started with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
`file` LIKE '%Amount Used%'
```

but am not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

When you replace the constants (ie,Amount Used , : ) , you will get the variable numbers

```
SELECT trim(replace(replace(`file`,'Amount Used',''),':','')) as `values`
FROM mytable 
WHERE `file` LIKE '%Amount Used%'
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da2f/6)